# Which AWS EC2 instance type is most optimal for audio streaming?

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio-streaming, flashmedialiveencoder

I'm in testing stage of launching an online radio. I'm using AWS CloudFormation stack with Adobe Media Server.

My existing instance type is m1.large and my Flash Media Live Encoder is streaming mp3 at 128kbps which i think is pretty normal but it's producing a stream that isn't smooth & stable at all and seems to have a lot of breaks.

Should i pick an instance type with higher specs?
I'm running my test directly off of LiveHLSManifest link that opens on my iPhone's Safari and plays on browser's build-in player..which doesn't set any buffering on client side - could this be the issue?

Comment: Your client has plenty of buffering built-in.  Plus if you're using HLS, you have an automatic buffer of the size of the last segment.  MP3 encoding on even a throttled micro instance is enough for a single stream at 128kbit.  Can you further debug where the issue is?  What's the loadavg on the box?  What type of streaming are you doing?  (Is it really HLS?)  If you run your iPhone through a proxy like Fiddler, can you see it making the requests and getting data in a timely manner?  (Better yet if you can put a packet sniffer like Wireshark on it, but that's trickier.)

Answer (score 0):

Testing HLS/HDS links directly on iPhone's Safari was a bad idea. I relied on built-in players already having some sort of buffering configuration by default but noo... I was able to receive stable & smooth stream when i used players like Strobe Media Playback, FlowPlayer etc.. Hopefully, this answer will save someone some time.